# OpenLayers color polygons on KML files

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

I want to print my kml files like in google maps but in OpenStreetMap.
So, with the example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/cross-origin-xml.html
I change in the cross-origin-xml.js : "format: new OpenLayers.Format.GPX()" by "format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML()" And it's works, BUT i got one problem, I cant get the REAL color of the polygons. They are all in : #ee9900.
My KML files works on google earth.

i want this result (with the polygons):http://maps.burningsilicon.net/index.php
(one kml file : valid for only 2 weeks): http://www.envoyercefichier.com/files/3e4722a6fe320566a31e5179c1ae458e.kml(dont click on it, just copy and paste in the textbox) and press go.

Please can you help me to get the good colors of my polygons ? :)

Comment: I'm new in osm api -_-
I know google earth api, but not this one.

If you got some GOOD links to learn to use OSM api, please let me know :)

Comment: This question is actually about OpenLayers, not about OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry. So actually, i got colors now.. it's just one property to add...extractStyles: true, and: extractAttributes: true, when i load the kml.
I use http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/kml-layer.html examples.